# Cannot run or jai_imageio or ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName cannot get Object

Tags: java, javax.imageio, jai

I'm running a program that using jai_imageio.jar and then validating if I can get ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tiff")

for some reason the program is running on other server, But when I checkout / load it into my server it always cause an error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

I've already spending half of my day with this.. but still can't figure it out.
I hope someone can tell what's wrong with my setup. 
Note (jai_imageio.jar and jai_code_codec-1.1.3-alpha.jar) is already in my eclipse WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding the jar files on the lib of my Tomcat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems I cannot delete this question and no answered it. I'm going to answer it. Just like the comment I post, adding the jar files of jai into the directory of tomcat resolve the problem.

Comment: actually, this is better.  Now the answer is obvious and since you haven't deleted it, it's still available for the next random googler.

Comment: Which jar files did you add, Give pom dependency section.